# Is it right approach to insert Many to One entity using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning Hibernate and Querydsl on spring boot application.

I'm not sure what i'm doing is right approach or not, This is how i insert many to one entity

```java
// BoardMaster.java

public void addBoards(Boards boards){
    this.boards.add(boards);
    boards.setBoardMaster(this);
}


// Service.java

@Override
@Transactional
public void save(BoardsRequestDto boardsRequestDto) {
    BoardMaster boardMaster = boardMasterService.getOne(boardsRequestDto.getBbsId());
    Boards boards = boardsRequestDto.toEntity();
    boardMaster.addBoards(boards);
    boardMasterRepository.save(boardMaster);
}
```

Boards is the entity has many to one relation and BoardMaster contains Boards entity as List.

So, first i try to get boardMaster and add boards into boardMaster finally run the save method.

I thought i should use or create update method to add boards into boardMaster but i found article that talks about save() can be use for update as well when i fetch entity from persistence context.
As this article says this method works fine but i'm not sure if this is fine. i feel like it's uncommon since i've never used hibernate before.

And i'm using Querydsl to update entity which feels uncommon as well

```java
@Override
public void modify(BoardMasterRequestDto boardMasterRequestDto, Long bbsId){
    queryFactory.update(boardMaster)
            .set(boardMaster.bbsName, boardMasterRequestDto.getBbsName())
            .set(boardMaster.bbsIntro, boardMasterRequestDto.getBbsIntro())
            .set(boardMaster.isPossibleToAttachFiles, boardMasterRequestDto.isPossibleToAttachFiles())
            .set(boardMaster.amountOfAttachment, boardMasterRequestDto.getAmountOfAttachment())
            .set(boardMaster.availableFileSize, boardMasterRequestDto.getAvailableFileSize())
            .set(boardMaster.isPossibleToReply, boardMasterRequestDto.isPossibleToReply())
            .set(boardMaster.templateId, boardMasterRequestDto.getTemplateId())
            .set(boardMaster.templateName, boardMasterRequestDto.getTemplateName())
            .set(boardMaster.useAt, boardMasterRequestDto.isUseAt())
            .set(boardMaster.bbsUseFlag, boardMasterRequestDto.getBbsUseFlag())
            .set(boardMaster.targetId, boardMasterRequestDto.getTargetId())
            .set(boardMaster.countOfComment, boardMasterRequestDto.getCountOfComment())
            .set(boardMaster.option, boardMasterRequestDto.getOption())
            .set(boardMaster.isPossibleToComment, boardMasterRequestDto.isPossibleToComment())
            .set(boardMaster.satisfaction, boardMasterRequestDto.getSatisfaction())
            .where(boardMaster.bbsId.eq(bbsId))
            .execute();
}
```

This method works fine as well but i'm sure there is more efficient way to update using Hibernate. Please give me some advice

If you guys need to more info, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is very abstract. I've always thought Hibernate is technically efficient enough to be used by so many applications, but if you aren't convinced, then explain why. For example, which part of your app performance you are concerned with here? Index updates or something else?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thank you for reply i'm just not sure if what i'm doing is fine approach to execute basic CRUD operations cause it's my first time using Hibernate. Just want to know how other people use Hibernate generally.

Comment: I'm afraid you better look at some other sites then. This is a knowledge base for relatively specific issues, and it's generally off-topic to ask here about how other people use Hibernate. As far as this site is concerned, if you haven't identified any problems with the approach, then it's off-topic.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I understand. Thank you